# How to allow user interaction with another window through a transparent Tauri app while alwaysOnTop is set to true

Tags: tauri

Is there a way to enable user interaction with another window through a transparent Tauri app, where the app's canvas contains images, and the **alwaysOnTop** property is set to true? Specifically, I would like to allow the user to click on another window that is positioned below the transparent Tauri app if the click is not on the image. Would that be possible?

Answer (score 0):

I read a closed issue in this [Tao repository](https://github.com/tauri-apps/tao/issues/184) and I was able to get what I describe above follow this [example created by a user](https://github.com/4t145/tauri-windows-clickthrough-example).
I am leaving this answer here in the hope of helping other people in the future.